# When it comes to handle errors, in what sense, using Exceptions are better that utilize if...else...switch... etc.?

Tags: php, exception

I perfectly understand the nuances of the (`try/throw/catch`) block.

What I don't understand is:

If we gonna use an `IF` (or any control structure) inside our `try` block anyway in order to test if a condition is met, only then, '`throw`' an exception if the results of that test is false, then... in my opinion: throw/generate an exception is useles; because if a condition is not met, we can simply print an error message, call a function, instantiate a class, redirect to another location, etc.

Another story would be, if for instance, a variable was not initialized, we enclose that variable inside a `try{}` block, echo the variable, and from that point onward, everything will be handle by the `catch()` block because the `try` block raises an error; and since the `try/catch` blocks talk each other, the catch block will catch every error that was originated from his corresponding try block. However, you can set a custom error message inside yout try block (optional).

What I've read so far:
every results from searching: [if vs. try](https://www.google.com.py/webhp?hl=en#hl=en&q=if+vs+try+catch)

I do see the difference.

But I can not understand why some people choose `try/throw/catch` over `if...else...switch...while`... etc.

As far I can see, `try/throw/catch` can be used for debugging, though.

Comment: Exceptions are ehm... exceptional which means that you would never be able to write as many `if` statements as needed to cover every possible error path. Also, exceptions are scope-unaware. If you'd use - lets say - a function utilising an invalid file pointer and then use this function in your code you would have no means to explicitly validate the pointer in your outer scope. Exception would bubble up through scopes to the first `try..catch` block.

Comment: @TeKo I can see your point, but in your example, there are lots of file handler functions to manage that scenario. I still can't see the usefulness of `try/catch` there.

Comment: Yeah, but you would then have to validate the said pointer in the lowest tightest possible scope (the function utilising it) and any error handling decision made here would affect every outer scope which is not very flexible.

Comment: Any function, should be as isolated as possible from the main code, making the skeleton of the final program as modular as possible. That said, you can have your custom error handler function, but you cannot handle all errors from one place. The logic of an intrinsic sub-routine must remain intrinsic. IMHO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One benefit of exceptions over `if/then` is that you can wrap `try/catch` around a large block of code. It will be triggered if an error happens anywhere in the block.

```
try {
    $db = db_open();
    $statement = $db->prepare($sql);
    $result = $statement->execute($params);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

With `if/then`, you would have to perform a test at each step.

```
$db = db_open();
if (!$db) {
    die(db_connect_error());
}
$statement = $db->prepare($sql);
if (!$statement) {
    die(db_error($db));
}
$result = $statement->execute($params);
if (!$result) {
    die(db_error($db));
}
```

Comment: Exactly Barmar. Your example complements what @CharlotteDunois said about a massive error. Now I can see more clearly. Thank you =***

Comment: Thank you all =***

Answer (score 2):

As you said, it's a lot of overhead to throw an exception inside a try/catch block and catch it immediately.

```
try {
  if (...) {
    // good, do no throw
  } else {
    throw new Exception();
  }
} catch ($e) {
  // handle exception
}
```

This should be replaced by:

```
if (...) {
  // good
} else {
  // handle error, no exception
}
```

Exceptions are useful because they bubble up. So imagine if you have this code instead:

```
function bla() {
  try {
    tryToDoSomething();
  } catch ($e) {
    // handle error
  }
}

function tryToDoSomething() {
  if ($somethingNotAvailable) {
    throw new Exception();
  }
  doSomething();
}
```

In this case, the function that defines the try/catch is NOT the one throwing the exception. tryToDoSomething() does not know how to handle the errors so it will let parent methods to take care of it. The exception can bubble up the call stack until someone catches it and handles the error. That's how exceptions can actually be useful :)

Comment: Adrien, almost. What I see in your example is a debugging scenario. Because if `$somethingNotAvailable`, I, (as the doctor), need to know why is not available. Where I'm going to find the answer?, Who's gonna tell me what's happening?: the `Exception` mechanism.

Comment: Exceptions aren't used for debugging. Exceptions are being used when the regular control flow cannot be continued, e.g. due to a massive error.

Comment: @klymax Not really. Exception is mainly just a signal to the outer scope to rollback to the nearest safe point and gracefully die.

Comment: I know that @TeKo, as I said: I perfectly understand the nuances of the (`try/throw/catch`) block.

Comment: You say the magic words @CharlotteDunois: "a massive error". And I know Exceptions aren't used for debugging, but not for testing if a small function can or cannot do something neither.